# Why my Regex to limit break lines doesn't work?

Tags: regex

I make a Regex `[0-9]\n{1}`to validate an lines of a numbers like

```
55555555
66666666
99999999
```

It works but not as I would like, since I would like it to only be the 3 lines and if I go beyond the 3 lines it tells me that there is an error, what can I do to make it work

Comment: You can't throw an error from RegEx because it's not a programming language. Just check if there's more than 3 matches in your code and throw an error if there is.

Comment: Use the regex `(\d+\n){4,}`. If this matches, throw an error.

Comment: @Jesse I know that it does not throw an error, I mean that the regular expression is not fulfilled

Comment: What regex flavor? Try [`\A\d+\n\d+\n\d+\z`](https://regex101.com/r/ravUI8/1) or [`^\d+\n\d+\n\d+$(?!\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/ravUI8/2)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to treat all the lines as a whole, you must apply the match operator to the whole (number + new line).
Then you limit the number of occurrences.

In addition, you close the end of the expression with `$`. The next line will no longer be accepted by which the expression will not be satisfied.

```
/(\d+\n?){1,3}$/m
```

The modifier `/m` (multiline) is mandatory.

Comment: This won't tell you whether or not there's more than 3 though (which is what the OP asked for), it will just match the first 3 and ignore the rest.

Comment: @Jesse It is true that it would be necessary to make it only 3 lines because if I write more it does not show that the regular expression is not fulfilled